# How to log every single command executed from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, command

I am trying to find a way to record every single command that is executed by any user on the system.
Things that I have came across earlier.

1. It is possible to view shell commands executed from the terminal using ~/.bashrc_history file.

There is a catch here, It logs only those commands which were executed interactively from bash shell/terminal.

This solves one of my problems. But in addition to it, I would like to log those commands also which were executed as a part of the shell script.

Note: I don't have control over shell script. Therefore, adding verbose mode like

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
```

is not possible.

However, this can be assumed that I have root access as a system administrator.

Eg: I have another user that has access to the system. And he runs the following shell script using from his account.

```
#!/bin/sh
nmap google.com
```

and run as "$ sh script.sh"

Now, What I want is "nmap google.com" command should be logged somewhere once this file is executed.

Thanks in advance. Even a small help is appreciated.

Edit: I would like to clarify that users are unaware that they are being monitored. So I need a solution something at system level(may be agent running with root). I cannot depend on user to log suspicious activity. Of-course everyone will avoid such tricks to put blame on someone else if they do something fishy or wrong

Comment: You don't run it this way under bash. I suggest to remove the _bash_ tag.

Comment: _#!/bin/bash -xe_  .... What's the purpose of the `-e`? It does not make sense to me. I would expect that you get an error message from it.

Comment: -e means exit if any error occurred while execution.

Comment: Ah, I missed the sentence _All  of the single-character shell options documented in the description of the set builtin command can be used as options when the shell is invoked_ in the man-page. Thank you for pointing thist out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware that you were asking for Bash and Shell scripting and tagged your question accordingly, but in respect to your requirements

- Record every single command that is executed by any user on the system
- Users are unaware that they are being monitored
- A solution something at system level

I am under the assumption that you are looking for [Audit Logging](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files).

So you may take advantage from articles like

- [Log all commands run by Admins on production servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/470755/)
- [Log every command executed by a User](https://serverfault.com/questions/336217/)

Comment: I found the auditd module of redhat linux (also available for ubuntu) https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sec-defining_audit_rules_and_controls
Link shows what and how to configure the audit logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script in this way:

- execute bash (it will override the shebang)
- ts to prefix every lines
- logs both in terminal and files

> bash -x script.sh |& ts | tee -a /tmp/$(date +%F).log

You may ask the other user to create an alias.

Edit:
You may also add this into /etc/profile (sourced when users login)

> exec > >(tee -a /tmp/$(date +%F).log)

Do it also for error output if needed. Keep it splited.

Comment: I would like to clarify that users are unaware that they are being monitored. So I need a solution something at system level. I cannot depend on user to log suspicious activity.
Of-course everyone will avoid such tricks to put blame on someone else if they do something fishy or wrong.

Comment: To monitor/spy other users, you have to get root permissions.
Otherwise, I guess it would be a critical security breach.
What do you think about periodic monitoring "ps" results?

Comment: I have the root permissions. ps would only return the on going process list.

Comment: What about adding into /etc/profile?
(I edited my first answer to have markdown working)